# Asynchronous updating list of options for multi select MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a form for user input, and one of the items (a multiple option select) has an inordinate amount of choices (~1600), so it's gotta get filtered down to be digestible. I've got 3 filter fields (dropdowns) that I'm requiring to have completed before I make an AJAX call back to the DB and get an updated list. It's similar to [How to filter the options of a drop down list using another drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304489/how-to-filter-the-options-of-a-drop-down-list-using-another-drop-down-list), however I also don't want to lose any items that were previously selected. Here's the signature for the function I've prototyped:

```
public JsonResult GetContentStandardsForUser(string type, string grade, string subject, List<SelectListItem> selected)
```

What I want is to return the new list of items (and not lose the ones that were already selected), and have the pick-list update.

What is this AJAX call going to look like (using jquery)? Should I just include the current selected values in my query, or can I pass the `SelectListItem`s like I've written above?

Comment: How do you mean you don't want to lose any items previously selected? You want users to select from this multi-option select, adjust the filters, and then continue making selections?

Comment: Yes, that's it. So, let's say they pick a content standard from grade 4, and then they change the filter to grade 5, I want the previous selection to stay in the set.

Comment: if it helps, think of it like picking a fantasy football team. I have a full set of all the NFL players in the league, and I want to be able to filter by QB/RB/WR, pick some players, adjust the filter, and not lose the players I already picked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some thought about the fantasy football example I presented, I came up with a solution. I make *two* multi-selects, one of available, one of selected. Only the "selected" list gets bound to the model-- the available list is what gets updated as a result of the query.

If someone can come up with a single-select control solution, I'm still interested, but this is a good workaround for me, for now. The reason I was looking for a single-select solution was that I was already using this plugin (http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) to filter my selected/available lists.

ETA: I realized I can do this in a single listbox with jquery. Using the ID, loop through the options, if it's not selected, remove it. Then add all new options from the query. Voila!

ETA2: Now with code!

```
        //Filter content standards
        $("#csType, #csGrade, #csSubject").change(function(){
            var type = $("#csType").val();
            var grade = $("#csGrade").val();
            var subject = $("#csSubject").val();

            if(type != "" && grade != "" && subject != "")
            {
                $("#csList option:not(:selected)").remove();

                var items="";
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetContentStandardsForUser","Summary")", {type:type, grade:grade, subject:subject} ,function (data) {
                    $.each(data,function(index,item){
                        items+="<option value='"+item.Value+"'>"+item.Text+"</option>"
                    });
                    $("#csList").append(items)
                    $("#csList").trigger('bootstrapduallistbox.refresh', true);
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

After binding the options, call following function.

```
$('#csList').multiselect('rebuild');
```