# Struggling with filtering dropdown with another dropdown ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

This is my first ASP.NET MVC application, and I'm really struggling with some stuffs, right now I have big issue and I'm stucked here for over 5 hours allready, I'm trying to filter my dropdown with selection from another dropdown, before I post my code I want to say that I've followed this post:

[How to filter the options of a drop down list using another drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304489/how-to-filter-the-options-of-a-drop-down-list-using-another-drop-down-list][1])

So let's start:

Regardless of the others fields, I have a lets say two dropdowns also, one represent MAIN CATEGORY, another represent SUB CATEGORY, and on MAIN CATEGORY selection, SUB CATEGORY should be loaded in dropdown and user should be able to choose it.

I want to create view where user should be able to fill some date and post it back to server, but before he post it back he need to choose date properly MAINCATEG -> SUBCATEG so this is how I did it so far:

My action result 'Create' method:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

// I did not wrote other stuffs because they are not important in my question and code will be clearer.

//First I'm filling MAIN CATEGORY dropdown with data from my database
    List<Groups> articleGroups = GroupController.GetActiveMainGroups();
    // Attach list on ViewBag, because this view Bag will be used to populate main dropdown
    ViewBag.articleGroups = articleGroups;


    //Here is second list which should populate second dropdown, right now I get all subgroups from database, because it didn't let me
    //run my application if list was empty (probably I don't need this in future because I will filter second dropdown by selecting something from dropdown above)
    List<SubGroups> subGroups = GroupController.GetAllSubGroups();
    // Attach list on ViewBag, it will be used for generating dropdown list.
    ViewBag.subGroups = subGroups;

    return View(model);
}
```

Here is also one method which I thought I can call throught javascript by triggering event 'change' on first (main) dropdown:

```
  public ActionResult GetSubgroupByMainGroup(Guid id)
  {
     List<SubGroups> subGroups = GroupController.GetAllSubGroupsByMainGroup(id);
     return Json(subGroups, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Here is my VIEW:

```
@model MyProject.Web.Models.ArticleNewViewModel
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
@using MyProject.Model
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add new Article";
}

<h3>Adding new article to database</h3>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainGroupID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MainGroupID, new SelectList(ViewBag.articleGroups , "MainGroupID", "Group.Name"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainGroupID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubGroupID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubGroupID, new SelectList(ViewBag.subGroups , "SubGroupID", "SubGroup.Name"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubGroupID)
            </div>
        </div>


    //I don't understand this code really, because I have so little experience with javascript&jquery
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#MainGroupID").change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var subItems="";
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetSubgroupByMainGroup", "Article")", {id:val} ,function (data) {
              $.each(data,function(index,item){
                subItems+="<option value='"+item.Value+"'>"+item.Text+"</option>"
              });
              $("#SubGroupID").html(subItems)
            });
        });
    });
</script>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Go back", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

It is interesting that when I set breakpoint in my method `public ActionResult GetSubgroupByMainGroup(Guid id)` it's not being hitted, that means this code is not executed, and here is my

```
ArticleNewViewModel
```

:

```
public class ArticleNewViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Article code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Article Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }


   //Here is ID's which should represent value from MAIN and value from SUBGROUP
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Main group")]
        public Guid MainGroupID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Sub Group")]
        public Guid SubGroupID { get; set; }


    }
```

I probably did few mistakes here but I really don't know where and what, because I'm not familiar with javascript & jquery, and I don't know is there another way to do it :/

Whatever I would like to fix this so if someone of you guys might help me I would appreciate so much!

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: Noone about this? :/

Comment: The code you have shown should hit the `GetSubgroupByMainGroup` method assuming your script is not in an external file. What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Note however that your code in the success callback is incorrect because you returning a collection of `SubGroups` which does not contain properties `Value` and `Text` (it appears that they contain properties `SubGroupID` and `SubGroupName`)

Comment: Refer also [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for implementing cascading dropdownlists.